# Context-Free-Grammar for assignment statements in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, antlr, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm writing an ANTLR lexer/parser for context free grammar.

This is what I have now:

```
statement
    :   assignment_statement
    ;

assignment_statement
    :   IDENTIFIER '=' expression ';'
    ;




term
    :   IDENT
    |   '(' expression ')'
    |   INTEGER
    |   STRING_LITERAL
    |   CHAR_LITERAL
    |   IDENT '(' actualParameters ')'
    ;

negation
    :   'not'* term
    ;

unary
    :   ('+' | '-')* negation
    ;

mult
    :   unary (('*' | '/' | 'mod') unary)*
    ;

add
    :   mult (('+' | '-') mult)*
    ;

relation
    :   add (('=' | '/=' | '<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>') add)*
    ;

expression
    :   relation (('and' | 'or') relation)*
    ;




IDENTIFIER : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

So my assignment statement is identified by the form

```
IDENTIFIER = expression;
```

However, assignment statement should also take into account cases when the right hand side is a function call (the return value of the statement). For example,

```
items = getItems();
```

What grammar rule should I add for this? I thought of adding a function call to the "expression" rule, but I wasn't sure if function call should be regarded as expression..

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you implement your grammar slowly piece by piece and test each rule. For example, it would identify for you that you have both IDENT and IDENTIFIER tokens.

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate a little more about the different between IDENT and IDENTIFIER..? Why should I have them separate?

Comment: Well, do you mean to have two different forms of identifer? IDENTIFIER and IDENT? Surely not.

Answer (score 1):

This grammar looks fine to me. I am assuming that IDENT and IDENTIFIER are the same and that you have additional productions for the remaining terminals.

This production seems to define a function call.

```
|   IDENT '(' actualParameters ')'
```

You need a production for the actual parameters, something like this.

```
actualParameters : nothing | expression ( ',' expression )*
```